# DELETE row from table takes very long

Tags: sql

I can't seem to figure out why executing a simple DELETE command against one of my tables takes so long. By long I mean 1:30.

The query is as follows:

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID AND UserName = ''
```

Of course it's not all that simple. The `Users` table has relationships to numerous other tables through foreign keys on the `UserID` column. Some of those tables in turn have relationships to other tables so, before deleting from the `Users` table I have to make sure that all references to the row in question from these other tables are deleted and before those rows can be deleted, all references to them in other tables must be deleted.

I don't use cascading deletion but I do have a list of SQL commands preceding the command above, that looks something like this:

```
DELETE FROM ThisTable 
WHERE ThisField IN (SELECT ThisField FROM OtherTable WHERE UserID = @UserID);

DELETE FROM ThatTable 
WHERE ThatField IN (SEECT ThatField FROM OtherTable WHERE UserID = @UserID);

DELETE FROM OtherTable WHERE UserID = @UserID;
```

It's much longer that just this but what I do know is that, when all of these queries have executed, there is no reference to `@UserID` in any of the related tables of `Users`. I know this because the `DELETE` doesn't fail, it just takes very long and I can't seem to figure out why. The `Users` table isn't particularly massive and has about 11K rows.

I've attached the estimated execution plan if it would be of any use. Would really appreciate some thoughts. What other tools can I use to figure out what is the time consuming part of my very simple query?

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: "By long I mean 1:30" - without context, that's a bit ambiguous. Do you mean 1 minute and 30 seconds, or 1 hour and 30 minutes?

Comment: look at the actual execution plan rather than the estimated. This will give you some real costs which will allow you to figure out what's happening

Comment: You've got many `JOINs` in your `DELETE` clause. They are going to be executed before doing the actual delete. If you really know that there are no more records, then skip the `JOINs`. Or else you need to show the actual statement along with the execution plan.

Comment: How many indexes are there on the table?   Do all of these indexes use the userid key?   Although 1m30s is long, particularly for a table with only 11K users, if a large number of indexes need to be updated because of the key, it could slow things down, particularly if your memory is tight or your SQL disk for tables is fragmented or otherwise not optimal.    Just something to also look at

Comment: Do tables ThisTable and ThatTable have indexes on UserId?

Comment: Sorry, lots of questions asked while I was out. Let me answer quickly. Yes, by 1:30 I mean 1min 30s. Sorry, should've been clear on that.

I did look at the actual execution plan and t looked pretty much exactly like the estimated execution plan. It doesn't tell me much though.

I realise there are many joins but, like I said, I made sure first that no keys will be violated. @MicSim, how do I "skip the JOINs"?

There is only one index on the Users table and that is on UserID. All the foreign keys also have indexes on UserID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to delete a record the database engine must actually check that you are not trying to remove a primary key that is referenced to in any foreign key (and also delete those FKs that have cascading deletes). You should have indexes on all foreign keys or their respective lookups will cause slow table scans.

If there are other active users in the same database, they can have locks on any of the secondary tables that make your delete block for long times.

Comment: I realise that. For the moment I'm just testing on my DEV database which have no other users. I realise that on the production DB it could be a problem but I'd first like to sort this issue out on the dev DB.

I do have indices on all the foreign keys so I would have expected the query to be much quicker. Is there any tools that I can use which would tell me where the time on my query is being used?

Comment: No wait, I was wrong. I thought I had indices on all the tables but I didn't. There were still some tables for which I did not have indices on the foreign key and that is exactly what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do this using joins.  If you can, add appropriate indexes do that, otherwise if indexing is the problem, you can even consider adding tables variables and then use them to do the ultimate delete.  Alt query below:

```
DELETE FROM ThisTable 
FROM 
    ThisTable 
inner join OtherTable
    OtherTable
on
    ThisTable.UserId = OtherTable.UserId
where
    OtherTable.UserId = @UserID

DELETE FROM ThatTable 
FROM 
    ThatTable 
inner join OtherTable
    OtherTable
on
    ThatTable.UserId = OtherTable.UserId
where
    OtherTable.UserId = @UserID

DELETE FROM OtherTable 
WHERE 
        UserID = @UserID;
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll have to read up a bit on join deletes but this doesn't explain why my query is slow and I don't see why this would be faster?

Comment: The DELETE only affects the "FROM TABLE" section, but allows you to tie it against other tables in a join. (FROM Table FROM JOINLIST).  Sometimes sub-queries perform differently than full joins.  I was going to suggest you look at adding additional criteria like ThisTable.CreateDate < OtherTable.CreateDate or any other fields that are mentioned in the indexes of This, That and Other tables.  Including the fields in the indexes make a HUGE difference.  Often if you only include half of the index, it does not use it at all.  As a last resort, you can try and create some table variables.

Comment: (..continued) with order by userId (or with indexes) to see if "pulling them out" as @krisku sort-of recommends will help any locks, etc.